How can I make MapView compass snap to north when followUserLocation prop is enabled for the Camera?
Using rnmapbox library, if I have followUserLocation set to true and I click on the compass to set it to north, it's glitching and keeps snapping back to where the orientation was. It doesn't change to North since the followUserLocation is set to true.
I don't know how to make a workaround for this, as the MapView doesn't have any ways of listening for compass presses (as far as I know).
Right now, this is my "Locate me" method, this is where the followUserLocation is set to true when the camera finished moving to the user's location:
    const goToUserLocation = useCallback(async () => {
      const locationOk = await checkLocation(goToUserLocation);

      if (!locationOk || !locationPermission || !userLocation || !cameraRef.current) return;

      setFollowUserLocation(false);

      setTimeout(() => {
        const commonSettings = {
          centerCoordinate: userLocation,
          animationMode: 'flyTo',
        };

        const modeSpecificSettings = isNavMode
          ? {
              zoomLevel: 17,
              pitch: 50,
              padding: {paddingTop: 300},
              animationDuration: 500,
              followZoomLevel: 5,
            }
          : {
              zoomLevel: 15,
              pitch: 25,
              padding: {paddingTop: 0},
              animationDuration: 1000,
            };

        cameraRef.current.setCamera({...commonSettings, ...modeSpecificSettings});

        setTimeout(() => {
          setFollowUserMode(
            isNavMode ? UserTrackingMode.FollowWithHeading : UserTrackingMode.Follow,
          );
          setFollowUserLocation(true);
        }, modeSpecificSettings.animationDuration);
      }, 10);
    }, [userLocation, cameraRef, isNavMode, locationPermission]);

Any help on how to solve this would be appreciated.
Here's a video to demonstrate the issue. I was pressing the compass several times, hence the repeated behavior. It keeps snapping back, it's not maintaining its NORTH orientation.
https://github.com/rnmapbox/maps/assets/113592108/a2408f5e-c568-40e8-8e9e-a5c772d0e7b6
My expected behavior is:

if the user presses the locate me button, the camera pans and stays in the center of the user's location and starts moving together with the user
if the user is not facing north, and decides to hit the compass button to reset orientation, the orientation should turn to north, while the camera still continues to move together with the user
as soon as the user touches the ViewPort, followUserLocation is set to false and the camera won't move along with the person anymore. In this case, compass behavior works as expected

